# jqGrid row selected but not highlighted

Tags: jqgrid

I want to select and unselect a row multiple times by clicking.

My code is so far: (`lastSelected` is a global `var`):

```
beforeSelectRow: function (id)
{
   if (lastSelected !== id) 
   {
     grid.setSelection(id);
     lastSelected = id;
     return;
   } 
   else
   {
     grid.resetSelection(id);
     lastSelected = null;
   }
}
```

The code works fine, but row is highlighted only after first click. The Second click unhighlight it and it keep being unhighlighted when I click it next times, but after 3rd, 5th... clicks it behave like selected (I have modal which pops up when row is selected), but is not highlighted.

Without `grid.getSelection(id)` it won't highlight at all, but still working like it was selecting and deselecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the main error in your code is the returned value of `beforeSelectRow`. If the returned value in not `false` then the standard processing will be continued and the row which you previously selected explicitly by usage `setSelection` can be unselected.

To fix the problem you should return `false` from `beforeSelectRow`. Additionally I would suggest to use `$(this)` instead of `grid` variable and to use standard `selrow` parameter of jqGrid instead of usage `lastSelected` variable. The resulting code could be the following

```js
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $self = $(this), selectedRowid = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");

    if (selectedRowid === rowid) {
        $self.jqGrid("resetSelection");
    } else {
        $self.jqGrid("setSelection", rowid, true, e);
    }

    return false; // don't process the standard selection
}
```

The corresponding demo is [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/unselectableRows.htm).